# Why is iFFT(FFT(S)) not yielding back S?

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to understand FFT in matlab and made a simple signal and subsequently show the FFT. It fails when doing the iFFT such that the signal is not restored properly. I would expect a full reconstruction of the signal S in Figure 3 but it seems its inverted?

```
clear all;
close all;
              
t = 0:0.01:10; 

S = (sin(2*pi*0.5*t));
figure;
plot(abs(S).^2)

X = fftshift(fft((S)));
X = abs(X)./max(max(X));
figure;
plot(abs(X).^2)

Y = abs(X).^2;
IFT = ifftshift(ifft(Y)); 
IFT = abs(IFT)./max(max(IFT));
figure;
plot(abs(IFT).^2)
```

[image: Compare Signal in Fig 1 with iFFT(FFT(S)) in Fig 3]

Comment: You're not computing `ifft(fft(s))`, you're computing `ifft(abs(fft(s)).^2)` (and with an additional normalization to boot). Why would you think that would yield your original signal back?

Comment: I'm linking a question that popped up today on my active questions list. It's Python, not MATLAB, but the concept is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks. So stoopit of me. But still, I am wondering why the result is inverted? abs(0)^2 should still be 0 ?

Comment: The FT of a sine (your input) is purely imaginary. The FT of a cosine is purely real. You start with a sine, take the FT, turn that into a purely real signal, then inverse transform. The result must be cosine! But note that you plot the magnitude square of the sine and cosine.